# Add a checkbox and label into a page with greasemonkey

Tags: javascript, forms, checkbox, label, greasemonkey

So I have a greasemonkey script that I am adding onto, and one of the features requires it to insert a checkbox and label onto a page.

So there are already 2 checkboxes and labels where I will be adding another, and I essentially just want to add my checkbox to the line after the current ones, but I have no idea how to do this.

Here is a snippit of code from where I want to add the new checkbox(i will include the entire form at the end)

```
<span class="smalltext">Type your reply to this message here.<br /><br />
                <label><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="postoptions[signature]" value="1" checked="checked" />&nbsp;<strong>Signature</strong></label><br />
                <label><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="postoptions[disablesmilies]" value="1" />&nbsp;<strong>Disable Smilies</strong></label></span>
```

So how can I insert a checkbox nad a label after the 2 that are already there

And how can I check if the checkbox is checked or not

Here is the entire form that has the checkboxs in it

```
<form method="post" action="newreply.php?tid=2292596&amp;processed=1" name="quick_reply_form" id="quick_reply_form">
<input type="hidden" name="my_post_key" value="de77ee8401edd4fe176f2c6a3787d411" />
<input type="hidden" name="subject" value="*" />

<input type="hidden" name="action" value="do_newreply" />
<input type="hidden" name="posthash" value="27dc484678c4aaceb647fc7e461bc869" id="posthash" />
<input type="hidden" name="quoted_ids" value="" id="quoted_ids" />
<input type="hidden" name="lastpid" id="lastpid" value="20693160" />
<input type="hidden" name="from_page" value="2" />
<input type="hidden" name="tid" value="2292596" />
<input type="hidden" name="method" value="quickreply" />

<table border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="4" class="tborder">

    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td class="thead" colspan="2">
                <div class="expcolimage"><img src="http://cdn2.myforums.net/images/blackreign/collapse.gif" id="quickreply_img" class="expander" alt="[-]" title="[-]" /></div>
                <div><strong>Quick Reply</strong></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody style="" id="quickreply_e">
        <tr>
            <td class="trow1" valign="top" width="22%">
                <strong>Message</strong><br />
                <span class="smalltext">Type your reply to this message here.<br /><br />
                <label><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="postoptions[signature]" value="1" checked="checked" />&nbsp;<strong>Signature</strong></label><br />
                <label><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="postoptions[disablesmilies]" value="1" />&nbsp;<strong>Disable Smilies</strong></label></span>

            </td>
            <td class="trow1">
                <div style="width: 95%">
                    <textarea style="width: 100%; padding: 4px; margin: 0;" rows="8" cols="80" name="message" id="message" tabindex="1"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="editor_control_bar" style="width: 95%; padding: 4px; margin-top: 3px; display: none;" id="quickreply_multiquote">
                    <span class="smalltext">
                        You have selected one or more posts to quote. <a href="./newreply.php?tid=2292596&amp;load_all_quotes=1" onclick="return Thread.loadMultiQuoted();">Quote these posts now</a> or <a href="javascript:Thread.clearMultiQuoted();">deselect them</a>.
                    </span>

                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="center" class="tfoot"><input type="submit" class="button" value="Post Reply" tabindex="2" accesskey="s" id="quick_reply_submit" /> <input type="submit" class="button" name="previewpost" value="Preview Post" tabindex="3" /></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simplicity's sake, do this with jQuery. If you don't already have it in your script, add this line to the [metadata block](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Metadata_Block):

```
// @require http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js
```

Then the code to add the checkbox and activate it is:

```
var checkboxCell    = $("#quickreply_e td:eq(0) span.smalltext");
if (checkboxCell.length) {
    checkboxCell.append (
        '<br><label><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="myVeryOwnCheckbox" value="1" />'
        + '&nbsp;<strong>My checkbox</strong></label>'
    );

    $("#quickreply_e input[name='myVeryOwnCheckbox']").change (myCheckboxChangeHandler);
}

function myCheckboxChangeHandler () {
    alert ("My checkbox was " + (this.checked ? "checked" : "unchecked") );
}
```

---

---

**Update:** Now that OP has given [the target site](http://www.hackforums.net/showthread.php?tid=2245813), verified that the code works against that site.  A complete working script is:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name    _Checkbox adder
// @include http://www.hackforums.net/showthread.php*
// @require http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js
// ==/UserScript==

var checkboxCell    = $("#quickreply_e td:eq(0) span.smalltext");
if (checkboxCell.length) {
    checkboxCell.append (
        '<br><label><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="myVeryOwnCheckbox" value="1" />'
        + '&nbsp;<strong>My checkbox</strong></label>'
    );

    $("#quickreply_e input[name='myVeryOwnCheckbox']").change (myCheckboxChangeHandler);
}

function myCheckboxChangeHandler () {
    alert ("My checkbox was " + (this.checked ? "checked" : "unchecked") );
}
```

Comment: Well this doesnt appear to work.  And I have no clue why because I have never really used jquery before

Comment: It works perfectly on a page with the structure you gave; I just mocked it up and tested it to be sure.  What version of Greasemonkey and Firefox are you using?  Are the existing checkboxes added by AJAX or javascript?  Link to the target page.  Uninstall and then reinstall the Greasemonkey script.

Comment: Well I copied the page structure directly out of the site I am trying to use it on.  And here is [link](http://www.hackforums.net/showthread.php?tid=2245813) to a page where this would be running(you may have to be a member

Comment: I tested the code against that site and it works flawlessly, although I did adjust it slightly for layout aesthetics.  Added a complete working script to the answer.

Comment: Thanks, for teh help, I dont know what was wrong with what I was doing but it works now.      But I have one more problem, I am also doing this on another page.  Same idea and everything so I assume I can reuse all the code except the var checkboxCell =... one.  So on the one above you start on the tbody and get more specific.  I can not figure out how to do the same with a page where there is no tbody tag, mainly because I am not a accustomed to jquery.  Now im out of characters so here is the page instead of me posting the code [here](http://www.hackforums.net/newreply.php?tid=2292403)

Comment: For that other page, you would use: `var checkboxCell    = $("#content input[name^='postoptions']").parents ("span.smalltext");` (all on one line).

Answer (score 0):

The idea is simple:

1. Find first cell in first row of table body with id "quickreply_e".
2. Create desired checkboxes.
3. Append created checkboxes to the end of cell child list.

Here is how you can find a cell:

```
var tbody = document.getElementById("quickreply_e");
var cell = tbody.rows[0].cells[0];
```

Elements are created with [`document.createElement`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_createelement.asp) and childs are appended with [`appendChild`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_appendchild.asp).  There are examples so all you need is to consistently call this two methods to create desired checkboxes.  I haven't written it for you since it is very boring task :)

Comment: How would I use append child.  I belive I understand how everything else works/is implemented except for that